# Importing the Lync/Skype Module

Tags: powershell, import, module, lync, skype-for-business

I'm trying to import the Skype for Business Online Connector module, but it's not going as planned. I'm following the steps outlined here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn362829(v=ocs.15).aspx

It should be super simple, but it refuses to import. If the download wasn't an installation, I'd understand that I'd need to create a folder and put the psm file in that folder, which would be put in the modules directory. But the site says once the module is installed, everything should be good to go.

Am I missing something incredibly obvious or something? I even tried the command Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector, as the installer doesn't mention Lync. But to no avail.

EDIT: The error message says:

> Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype for Business
>   Online\Modules\SkypeOnlineConnector\SkypeOnlineConnectorStartup.psm1
>   cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: When you say, "_it refuses to import..._" do you mean you get an error?  What, explicitly, does the error say (show us)?  Also, when the module has 'Lync' in the title, don't assume that you're expecting Lync to be installed (it may just be a naming thing that they carried over from dropping Lync).

Comment: Sorry, it says "Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\Common Files\Skype for Business 
Online\Modules\SkypeOnlineConnector\SkypeOnlineConnectorStartup.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts 
is disabled on this system."

Answer (score 1):

Execution policy errors are one of the easiest fixes to running PowerShell scripts.  Here's a few links to help explain what the issue is you've run into:

- [How to enable execution of scripts in
  PowerShell](https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts)
- [SS64: Set-ExecutionPolicy](http://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html)

You can either add a `ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` switch to your call of PowerShell, or can use `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to permanently change the execution policy on your system.

Do read up on the different policies, however, and consider leaving the policy at least on `RemoteSigned` for protection.  While you can `Bypass` or `Unrestricted` the policy, it would leave your system potentially vulnerable to malicious scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting as an answer (the checkmark beneath the voting arrows) if this fixed your issue for you.